# How to use the XGraphicsExposeEvent to draw something by Qt

Tags: qt, gtk, x11

```
typedef struct {
        int type;
        unsigned long serial;   /* # of last request processed by server */
        Bool send_event;        /* true if this came from a SendEvent request */
        Display *display;       /* Display the event was read from */
        Drawable drawable;
        int x, y;
        int width, height;
        int count;              /* if non-zero, at least this many more */
        int major_code;         /* core is CopyArea or CopyPlane */
        int minor_code;         /* not defined in the core */
} XGraphicsExposeEvent;
```

we always can use the field [drawable] to paint something by GTK, like this :

```
GdkNativeWindow nativeWinId = (XID)((void*)(expose->drawable));
...
...
// draw something by GdkNativeWindow with gtk APIs.
```

but how about Qt?

Comment: Where does the event come from? Is the window a `QWidget`? Please describe why you want to do this.

Comment: no. the event come from the method "NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance, void* event)", that's the standard NPAPI methods, because in my platform there's no GTK releated libs, I cant draw the plugin UI by GTK, **but the Qt exists**, so I need to draw something by Qt with the XEvent.